# Plotly: How to create an odd number of subplots?

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-python

I want the 5th subplot to be in the centre of the two columns in the third row. (I have tried doing that by adding the `domain` argument). Here is the code to reproduce it-

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

continent_df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vyaduvanshi/helper-files/master/continent.csv')
temp_cont_df = pd.pivot_table(continent_df, index='continent', aggfunc='last').reset_index()

fig = make_subplots(rows=3, cols=2, specs=[[{'type':'pie'},{'type':'pie'}],[{'type':'pie'},{'type':'pie'}],
                                           [{'type':'pie'},{'type':'pie'}]])

fig.add_pie(labels=continent_df.continent, values=continent_df.new_cases, row=1,col=1)
fig.add_pie(labels=continent_df.continent, values=continent_df.new_deaths, row=1,col=2)
fig.add_pie(labels=continent_df.continent, values=continent_df.new_recovered, row=2,col=1)
fig.add_pie(labels=continent_df.continent, values=continent_df.new_tests, row=2,col=2)
fig.add_pie(labels=temp_cont_df.continent, values=temp_cont_df.active_cases, row=3,col=1,domain={'x':[0.25,0.75],'y':[0,0.33]})
```

[image]

If I do not include the 6th plot in the `specs` argument, it throws an error.

Comment: Does this [doc](https://plotly.com/python/subplots/#multiple-custom-sized-subplots) help you?

Comment: It does! Just adding a `'colspan':2` to the second last specs argument and making the last one `None` does the trick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this through a correct setup of `domain`. Here's an example that will have a figure in each of the four corners and one figure in the middle.

#### Plot

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

labels = ['Oxygen','Hydrogen','Carbon_Dioxide','Nitrogen']
values = [4500,2500,1053,500]
domains = [
    {'x': [0.0, 0.33], 'y': [0.0, 0.33]},
    {'x': [0.33, 0.66], 'y': [0.33, 0.66]},
    {'x': [0.0, 0.33], 'y': [0.66, 1.0]},
    {'x': [0.66, 1.00], 'y': [0.0, 0.33]},
    {'x': [0.66, 1.0], 'y': [0.66, 1.00]},
]
traces = []

for domain in domains:
    trace = go.Pie(labels = labels,
                   values = values,
                   domain = domain,
                   hoverinfo = 'label+percent+name')
    traces.append(trace)

layout = go.Layout(height = 600,
                   width = 600,
                   autosize = False,
                   title = 'Main title')
fig = go.Figure(data = traces, layout = layout)
#py.iplot(fig, show_link = False)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to it the `domain` way (your way) as well as by editing the last bit of my `specs` argument. Either way works fine

Comment: `specs=[[{'type':'pie'},{'type':'pie'}],[{'type':'pie'},{'type':'pie'}],
                                           [{'type':'pie','colspan':2},None]]`

Comment: The [domain](https://i.imgur.com/OMnVFdI.png) one looks better though because of the finer control compared to the strict column and row restrictions of the [specs](https://i.imgur.com/tK4Xus6.png) way (though I am sure there is a workaround for that too)